# Как узнать индекс двух одинаковых элементов в списке

Tags: python, list, search

У меня есть следующий список:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
```

Как мне получить все индексы числа 1

Answer (score 3):

пусть `a` - исходный список, `num` - число, которое мы ищем

Способ 1

```
a = [1,2,3,4,1,5]
num = 1
idx=[x[0] for x in enumerate(a) if x[1] == num]
print(idx)
```

> [0, 4]

Способ 2

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4,1,5]
num=1
idx = np.argwhere(np.array(a) == num).flatten()
print(idx)
```

> [0 4]

Answer (score 2):

Например для известного элемента так:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,1,5]
a = 1
for i, name in enumerate(i):
   if name == a:
      res.append(i)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419204/index-of-duplicates-items-in-a-python-list) :

```
>>> def duplicates(lst, item):
...   return [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == item]
... 
>>> duplicates(List, "A")
[0, 2]
```

```
>>> dict((x, duplicates(List, x)) for x in set(List) if List.count(x) > 1)

{'A': [0, 2]}
```

```
>>> List.index("A")
0
>>> List.index("A", 1)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать метод count для отбора элементов, встречающихся два раза

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,1,5]
res = [i for i,x in enumerate(lst) if lst.count(x) == 2]
print(res)
[0,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно пройтись по списку циклом for и после совпадения удалять нужный элемент, а его
индекс добавлять в новый список. Но не нужно забывать, что после каждого удаления числа из списка индекс смещается на 1, поэтому нужно добавить счетчик(count)

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1]
ind = [] 
count = 0
for f in lis:
    if f == 1:
        ind.append(lis.index(f) + count)
        lis.remove(f)
        count += 1
print(*ind)
```

Ну или же просто вместо индекса элемента можно добавлять число, на которое ссылается переменная count

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1]
ind = []
count = 0
for f in lis:
    if f == 1:
        ind.append(count)
    count += 1
print(*ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для разнообразия ещё такой метод - поиск через `index`, начиная с указанной позиции:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
n = 1
j = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = arr.index(n, j)
        print(i)
        j = i + 1
    except:
        break
```

Вывод:

```
0
4
```