# Как найти индексы повторяющихся элементов?

Tags: python, list

Как в списке строк получить индексы повторяющихся элементов?

```
l = ['стул', 'кровать', 'стол', 'стул', 'диван', 'стол']  # список
```

Надо получить:

```
0 3
2 5
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У Вас сразу 3 вопроса. Причём на каждый в отдельности несложно найти ответ. Если у Вас всё-таки возникнут сложности, то конкретизируйте внимание на чём-то одном, и Вам постараются помочь

Comment: [Как найти индексы повторяющихся элементов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117564)

Answer (score 1):

Ну например прямо вот "в лоб" решение. Составляем словарь, где ключ - элемент списка, а значения - список индексов, по которым он встречается. И где получится больше одного элемента список такой в итоге, то печатаем его:

```
l = ['стул', 'кровать', 'стол', 'стул', 'диван', 'стол']  # список
indexes = {}
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    indexes[v] = indexes.get(v, []) + [i]
for v in indexes.values():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(*v)
```

Вывод:

```
0 3
2 5
```

Comment: Благодарочка!!!

Comment: @Cyber_Michael, [как принято говорить "спасибо" на SO (StackOverflow) ;)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)